# Send mail in list event receiver work only for site owners

Tags: development, event-receivers, email

I have simple event receiver start after save item, do something and send mail, there is part of code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
{
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(settings.MailSender, settings.MailSenderTitle);
mailMessage.Subject = subject;
mailMessage.Body = stringBuilder.ToString();
mailMessage.To.Add(to);
SmtpClient smptClient = new SmtpClient(settings.MailSMTP);
smptClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
smptClient.Send(mailMessage);
});
```

It's work only if the user has full control permissions. I try change smptClient.Credentials to new NetworkCredential(ReadAppSettings.SP_SuperUser, ReadAppSettings.SP_SuperUserPassword, "domain"); but  the same issue.
But if the user that not have full control created for them self for example alter on list a do some change, server will send to him mail.
So i thinking that my problem is in code, so how force code to sending mail if user don't have permission.